# Carthage build after update for specific platforms

Tags: ios, carthage

Is it possible to tell the `carthage update` command to build for certain platforms after it downloads source code?
Something like `carthage update --platforms iOS | watchOS`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were close..

```
carthage update --platform iOS,watchOS
```

Landed here since I tried to find out the same thing, then realized:

```
carthage help update
```

"the platforms to build for (one of 'all', 'macOS', 'iOS', 'watchOS', 'tvOS', or comma-separated values of the formers except for 'all')"

Comment: Yeah I found it. Thanks